# Haskell MonadError

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads

I was looking at a tutorial on monads in haskell
i came across this type class:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadError e m | m -> e where
    throwError :: e -> m a
    catchError :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a
```

I was wondering why the type parameters are e then m, i would have thought it would be m then e because when i looked at an instance for this class:

```
instance MonadError (Either e) where 
throwError = Left 
(Left e) `catchError` handler = handler e 
a        `catchError` _       = a
```

The monad constructor either came first, so my question is why in the class declaration are the type parameters switched?

Comment: Where did you see `instance MonadError (Either e) where ...`? Note that the MonadError  [defined in mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#t:MonadError) is different from the one [defined in monads-tf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monads-tf-0.1.0.3/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t:MonadError)

Comment: @ErikR hey, i saw it defined in this tutorial: https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Error_monad

Comment: I think the tutorial has a typo: it should read `instance MonadError e (Either e) where`